# Is my multi-threaded "fizz buzz" implementation thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

For educational purposes I am implementing classical "fizz buzz" problem using multiple threads.

"fizz buzz" game is:

> The player designated to go first says the number "1", and each player thenceforth counts one number in turn. However, any number divisible by three is replaced by the word fizz and any divisible by five by the word buzz. Numbers divisible by both become fizz buzz

In my implementation I have 4 threads:

- First thread prints number if it is not multiple of 3 or 5 and increment current counter.
- Second thread prints “fizz”...
- Third thread prints “buzz”...
- Forth thread prints “fizz buzz”...

I don't use any locking and thread synchronizations mechanisms.
Is my multi-threaded "fizz buzz" implementation thread safe? And, if not, why?
I added comments in code of implementation for "suspicious" places.

My Implementation:

```
package threads;    
import java.util.function.IntFunction;    
public class FizzBuzzGameRunner {

    // not volatile
    // if other thread updates currentNum and current thread will see old (cached) value
    // nothing bad can happen, just burn some CPU cycles uselessly
    private int currentNum = 1;

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        FizzBuzzGameRunner fizzBuzzGame = new FizzBuzzGameRunner();
        startAll(
                fizzBuzzGame.createRunnable(n -> (n % 3 != 0 && n % 5 != 0) ? String.valueOf(n) : null),
                fizzBuzzGame.createRunnable(n -> (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 != 0) ? "fizz" : null),
                fizzBuzzGame.createRunnable(n -> (n % 3 != 0 && n % 5 == 0) ? "buzz" : null),
                fizzBuzzGame.createRunnable(n -> (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0) ? "fizz buzz" : null)
        );
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    private static void startAll(Runnable... workers) {
        for (Runnable w : workers) {
            Thread t = new Thread(w);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    private Runnable createRunnable(IntFunction<String> singleStep) {
        return () -> {
            while (true) {
                int currNum = this.currentNum;
                // no synchronization
                String result = singleStep.apply(currNum);
                if (result != null) {
                    //Even without synchronization this block will be
                    //executed maximum by single thread simultaneously.
                    //Because each thread increments this.currentNum as part of that action,
                    //but no other thread will increment for the same value.
                    System.out.println(result);
                    this.currentNum++;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I understand that my example is totally artificial. To implement multi-threaded "Fizz Buzz" algorithm inspired one famous book for preparation for "codding interview". I just wanted to proof that example in book (which required to have 4 threads) can be solved without using synchronization and locks.

Comment: @matt I think the idea is (though the question could do with some more explanation ...) that only the thread that satisfies its condition will increment currNum. Therefore each thread does nothing until the other threads bump currNum to an appropriate value (in each case causing output of their appropriate nature, "fizz" or "buzz" or "fizzbuzz" or a number). It's trickier than it first appears.

Comment: @davmac in my example, one thread updates curNum between A geting the value and B getting the value. eg. currentNum = 9, A reads that value and assigns curNum to 9, thread C updates currentNum, thead B assigns curNum = 10; now A and B both have the correct value and it is a race. Oh, your saying A cant get 9 before C updates otherwise C would have a 9.

Comment: @matt I don't follow. What do you mean by "correct value"? Each thread has a disjoint set of values that they will act on. Each thread increments curNum as part of that action, but no other thread will increment for the same value. In your example if A reads curNum as 9 and then C updates curNum, then it must be because C saw curNum as having a value that it would act on, meaning that neither 9 nor the value that C saw is a value that A will act on, so it doesn't matter which one it has.

Comment: "correct value" being the value that the specific thread operates on. Right so C would have to see an 8 and act, then update the value from 9 to 10 which could happen if C saw an old value. Since thread C is the only one that would modify 8 to 9, it can't see a stale value.

Comment: @matt right, I think we are on the same page now.

Comment: "Thread safe" is not an attribute of programs: It's an attribute of a library/package/module/etc. that informs you about what precautions you must take when using it _in_ a program.  All you can say about the program as a whole is, it either works, or it doesn't work.

Comment: @Solomon Slow I understand thread safe as "Thread-safe code only manipulates shared data structures in a manner that ensures that all threads behave properly and fulfill their design specifications without unintended interaction" (took from wikipedia)

Comment: @Solomon Slow I understand that my example is totally artificial. To implement multi-threaded "Fizz Buzz" algorithm inspired one famous book for preparation for "codding interview". I just wanted to proof that example in book (which required to have 4 threads) can be solved without using synchronization and locks.

Comment: D'Oh! Comment retracted.

Comment: You changed the question, so that the variable is now `volatile`. The question is now asking a different question to the one that was asked and answered! You shouldn't do that - please change it back. If you want to ask if `volatile` is sufficient, you should open another question and refer to this one.

Comment: @davmac valid point - changed back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not race-free (which is what I think you are really asking), because the threads read from `currentNum` when it has been written by another thread, without any synchronisation. Each thread is not guaranteed to see the latest value - each thread will see either the value it last wrote itself, or any value that any other thread has written since.

What this could mean is that you end up with no forward progression in any thread, since each thread may simply fail to see the change made in any other. You could use an `AtomicInteger` to solve that problem.

I'm not sure, also, whether the effects of `this.currentNum++;` are guaranteed to be seen to other threads as ordered in the same way that they are in the source thread. I suspect that theoretically, the output and increment could be re-ordered, for example:

```
              this.currentNum++;
              System.out.println(result);
```

This could lead to inconsistent output.

Comment: I think line  "this.currentNum++" will can be reached just by single thread simultaneously, because only for single thread "result  = 
 singleStep.apply(currNum)" can be not null simultaneously. So this.currentNum++; and System.out.printLn will be never executed by multiple threads

Comment: @Palladium why do you think that  "result = singleStep.apply(currNum)" can't be not null simultaneously in multiple threads?

Comment: @Palladium You have 4 threads running simultaneously, there's no synchronization anywhere that prevents those threads from accessing currNum at the same time, or prevents threads from processing the same currNum , or makes sure the output order is is proper

Comment: @davmac because "singleStep.apply(currNum);" can return not null only then currNum is “appropriate” for current thread, and that can happen only for one thread simultaneously.

Comment: @Palladium it is icky. You might be right that the increment cannot happen simultanously from different threads. But there are still significant issues. I've re-worded the answer.

Comment: @davmac Why output and increment can be reordered? (I agree that would be problem)

Comment: I aggree "I can end up with not forward progression" (because it is possible for one thread not see "cached" values for long time), wouldn't it be the same if I use volatile int currentNum = 1" instead "AtomicInteger currentNum = new  new AtomicInteger(1)"?

Comment: @Palladium q1: because in general without synchronisation a thread can see the actions of another thread occur in a different order. q2: yes I think that `volatile` would be sufficient actually.

Comment: Btw.: I think best  solution (performance improved about 4 times on my machine)  would be to make all block which check and increments value of currentNum synchronized.